# Get first day of first month of previous year in yyyy-mm-dd format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, select

How do I get the first day of the first month of previous year in `yyyy-mm-dd` format? ie. `2019-01-01`.
This is the code I have tried:

```
SELECT DATEADD(yy,-1,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DATEFROMPARTS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function in SQL Server for creating date from given year, month and date in integer as shown below. To get the previous year you can use `Year()` function and subtract `1` from that. First date and month is always `1` so it has been hard-coded here.

```
declare @IntYear int = Year(Getdate()) - 1 --Previous Year
Select datefromparts(@Intyear, 1, 1)
```

The output in SSMS is as shown below.
[image]

To get the output in the different format you can follow this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking to generate a string, not a date. Consider using date functions and string concatenation: you just need to substract 1 year from the current date, and then append `'-01-01'`

```
concat_ws('-', year(getdate()) - 1, '01', '01')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0018283be527bbc3c60e825289d01a9f)**

Answer (score 1):

You basically have it.  You just need the `FORMAT` function.

`SELECT FORMAT (DATEADD(yy,-1,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0)), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as date`